# Are mnemonic for wizard navigation supported in install4j?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to configure mnemonics for the navigation button in install4j version 6.0.1? I searched for some configuration fields without success and also get no hint at the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mnemonics are currently not supported. ALT-Left and ALT-Right trigger the navigation buttons.